# One single Link that will open a seperate page and specific iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, hyperlink, href

I got a situation here. I have a main page and a subpage. The subpage does have an iframe container and there are two pages test1.htm and test2.htm that are loaded into that iframe when your current page is "subpage.htm".

However, what I want to to, is to be able to click on a link on my main page and it opens up the subpage and automatically loads a predefined page, lets say test1.htm into the iframe.

I got the function to load a page into an iframe and I though by using JavaScript and some code this was possible. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

```
function link {
url = '../subpage.htm';
document.target = url;
loadintoiframe(myiframe,test1.htm);
}
```

I got the function loadintoiframe, it needs the name of the iframe and the page to load. 
When I call the function link() as a href link on the main page, it does load the subpage, but it does not load the iframe correctly.

Maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: Are people still using iframes instead of divs?

Comment: Mark, we don't judge we just help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put

```
<a href="test1.htm" target="iframeID">Link</a>
```

And avoid the JavaScript at all?

Comment: I want to click on a link. When I do that, I want to load a different page (that has an iframe container) and a specific page in that iframe container. 
I dont think that code will do the job, or will it?

Comment: Give the iframe an ID and set the target attribute to the iframe's ID. As far as I know whatever is in the link's href value will pop up in the targeted iframe.

Comment: This might just be what I wanted. I'll try this when I get home, Im at work right now :D

Answer (score 0):

So this does not work. 
I tried to go for a JavaScript Method that just does a href basically and then calls the method that loads my special page into that iframe on the href site.

That did not work, so anyone else got a clue how I can href a different .htm site and simultaniously tell that site to load a certain page into the iframe?

Best regards,
Alex